# Change record props with custom input

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, admin-on-rest

I have a resource with **x** and **y** coordinates and I'm trying to create custom input with map from where to get these coordinates. But I can't change the record props. I tried with two [hidden] **Field** components, but I can't change their values as well.

---

**Update:**
I found the solution here: [admin-on-rest, redux-form, and trimming field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121597/admin-on-rest-redux-form-and-trimming-field-values)

Comment: You need to post the code that you have tried yet.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fV0EyAxp - this is the code.
I'm pretty sure that I can't change the Field values like that, but I can't find how to do it.